# javascript cost of comparison with undefined

Tags: javascript, performance

While messing around with JavaScript I found that comparing an array element with undefined was very interesting. Considering:

```
L = [1,2,3];
if (L[1] == undefined)
  console.log('no element for key 1');
else
  console.log('Value for key 1'+L[1]);
```

I think thats an awesome way to check for values in sequences in JavaScript, instead of iterating over sequences or other containers, but my question is: is that error prone or not efficient? Whats the cost of such comparison?

Comment: _"[...] instead of iterating over sequences or other containers"_ -- Can you explain in more detail, what do you mean? Maybe post an example of code for that case to see the difference.

Comment: Err, you get around 10~12x increase in so-called "performance" if you use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Well, I was just wondering if that was a harmful comparison or I really could do that as an easier way of looking for elements in lists without loosing execution speed. Thanks for that comments. \o

Comment: instead of calling these items `key` you should think these as `index`.

Comment: In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/syEYj/) you can call these as `1,2,3` `key`.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not test if a *particular value* exists; it tests if an [Array] index was *assigned* a non-undefined value. (It will also incorrectly detect some false-positive values like `null` due to using `==`, but that's for another question ..)

Consider this:

```
L = ["hello","world","bye"]
a = L["bye"]
b = L[1]
```

What is the value of `a` and what does it say about "bye"? What is the value of `b` and how does `1` relate to any of the values which may (or may not) exist as elements of L?

That is, *iterating* an Array - to find a value of unknown index? to perform an operation on multiple values? - and *accessing an element by index* are two *different* operations and cannot be generally interchanged.

---

On the flip side, object properties can be used to achieve a similar (but useful) effect:

```
M = {hello: 1, world: 1, bye: 1}
c = M["hello"]
```

What is the value of `c` now? How does the value used as the key relate to the data?

In this case the *property name* (used as a *lookup key*) relates to the data being checked and can say something useful about it - yes, there *is* a "hello"! (This can detect some false-positives without using `hasOwnProperty`, but that's for another question ..)

---

And, of course .. for a small sequence, or an infrequent operation, iterating (or using a handy method like [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)) to find existence of a value is "just fine" and will not result in a "performance impact".

Answer (score 0):

In V8 accessing array out of bounds to elicit `undefined` is unspeakably slow because for instance if it's done in optimized code, the optimized code is thrown away and deoptimized. In other languages an exception would be thrown which is very very slow too or in unmanaged language your program would have undefined behavior and for example crash if you're lucky.

So always check the `.length` of the collection to ensure you don't do out of bounds accesses.

Also, for performance prefer `void 0` over `undefined` as it is a compile time constant rather than runtime variable lookup.